# JCS CompositeCacheAttributes cannot be cast to ICompositeCacheAttributes

Tags: java, jcs

I am using JCS which I have used before in the same way without any problem.

When the server starts up I am setting the cache properties manually

```
CompositeCacheManager ccm = CompositeCacheManager.getUnconfiguredInstance();
Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("jcs.default", "");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes.MaxObjects", "1000");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName", "org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker", "true");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds", "3600");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds", "60");
    props.put("jcs.default.elementattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.default.elementattributes.IsEternal", "false");

    ccm.configure(props);
```

When setting this way an error is being thrown

```
org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.jcs.engine.behavior.ICompositeCacheAttributes
```

I have used this exact same method on other projects without problem. Why am I getting this exception now?

**EDIT**

I am getting the JCS jar file from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jcs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Prior to this I also tried to get the 2.0-beta version with the same problem

**EDIT 2**

I have opened a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCS-150) in Jira, should anyone else be facing the same problem and wish to follow.

Comment: Any clue on this issue . I am also in similar situation

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of tries, had found that this issue is with the dependencies. Below set of dependencies worked for me

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jcs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcs</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>concurrent</groupId>
        <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

INSTEAD OF -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-jcs-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Selecting the right set of dependencies solved the problem for me.